# Installation error Agda: unrecognized option `x'

Tags: haskell, installation, cabal, agda

I'm trying to install Agda on windows 10 but I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin>cabal install Agda
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-7.0.1 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - Win32-2.3.0.0 (lib:Win32) (requires build)
 - haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1 (lib:haskell-src-exts) (requires build)
 - vector-0.11.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - zlib-0.5.4.2 (lib) (requires build)
 - time-1.3 (lib:time) (requires build)
 - hashtables-1.2.1.1 (lib) (requires build)
 - directory-1.2.0.1 (lib:directory) (requires build)
 - cpphs-1.18.9 (exe:cpphs) (requires build)
 - Agda-2.4.2.2 (lib:Agda, exe:agda, exe:agda-mode) (requires build)
Starting     zlib-0.5.4.2 (lib)
Starting     vector-0.11.0.0 (lib)
Starting     Win32-2.3.0.0 (all, legacy fallback)
Starting     haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1 (all, legacy fallback)
Building     vector-0.11.0.0 (lib)
Building     zlib-0.5.4.2 (lib)
Building     Win32-2.3.0.0 (all, legacy fallback)
Building     haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1 (all, legacy fallback)

Failed to build Win32-2.3.0.0.
Build log (
C:\Users\nicod\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\ghc-7.0.1\Win32-2.3.0.0-bc0070ef9ddaa5b276f777956fac43c90ce6de13.log
):
Preprocessing library for Win32-2.3.0.0..
unrecognized option `-x'
Usage: hsc2hs.exe [OPTIONS] INPUT.hsc [...]

  -o FILE          --output=FILE          name of main output file
  -t FILE          --template=FILE        template file
  -c PROG          --cc=PROG              C compiler to use
  -l PROG          --ld=PROG              linker to use
  -C FLAG          --cflag=FLAG           flag to pass to the C compiler
  -I DIR                                  passed to the C compiler
  -L FLAG          --lflag=FLAG           flag to pass to the linker
  -i FILE          --include=FILE         as if placed in the source
  -D NAME[=VALUE]  --define=NAME[=VALUE]  as if placed in the source
                   --no-compile           stop after writing *_hsc_make.c
  -v               --verbose              dump commands to stderr
  -?               --help                 display this help and exit
  -V               --version              output version information and exit

Failed to build haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1.
Build log (
C:\Users\nicod\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\ghc-7.0.1\haskell-src-e_-1.14.0.1-bb66f1bc440947654b6bec6b775e21dbc0b1d6a7.log
):
Building haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1...
Preprocessing library haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1...
[ 1 of 22] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Annotated.Syntax ( src\Language\Haskell\Exts\Annotated\Syntax.hs, dist\build\Language\Haskell\Exts\Annotated\Syntax.o )

src\Language\Haskell\Exts\Annotated\Syntax.hs:122:39:
    Can't make a derived instance of `Foldable ModuleName':
      You need -XDeriveFunctor to derive an instance for this class
    In the data type declaration for `ModuleName'

src\Language\Haskell\Exts\Annotated\Syntax.hs:122:48:
    Can't make a derived instance of `Traversable ModuleName':
      You need -XDeriveFunctor to derive an instance for this class
    In the data type declaration for `ModuleName'
```

Followed by a lot more similar error messages. According to the error-message the problem is that Win32 can't be installed, but I have no idea what is wrong and how to solve it. Can anybody help?

Comment: You're running a very old GHC.

Comment: I have version 8, which should be okay I guess C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin>stack exec -- ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.4

Comment: It's not the one that's picked up by the build system though: `Build profile: -w ghc-7.0.1 -O1`

Comment: I see, is there a way to let the let the build system pick up the ghc version on stack?

Comment: Seems [Agda v2.6.1.3](https://www.stackage.org/lts-17.8/package/Agda-2.6.1.3) is on latest stack - so if you us lts-17.8 for your global project you should be able to just `stack install agda` and it should bring agda into your `~/stack/bin`